# org.openqa.selenium.UnsupportedCommandException error on appium scroll

Tags: java, android, automation, appium

[Model Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wW2RS.png)I am trying to scroll to a particular element in the screen, getting the below error:

Eclipse Error log:

```
org.openqa.selenium.UnsupportedCommandException: The requested resource   could not be found, or a request was received using an HTTP method that is not  supported by the mapped resource. (Original error: That device doesn't know how  to respond to 'mobile: 'scroll--it's probably not using Appium's API) (WARNING:  The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
     Command duration or timeout: 13 milliseconds
```

Below is the Appium error logs:

```
> info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session/0b79ffed-89dc-66ca-27b0-   cf6ef260181a/element 200 18.561 ms - 122 
> info: --> POST /wd/hub/session/0b79ffed-89dc-66ca-27b0- cf6ef260181a/execute {"script":"mobile: scroll","args":  [{"direction":"down","element":"c845c15a-918c-019f-67a0-ae6a1dbe34c5"}]}
 > info: [debug] Responding to client with error: {"status":9,"value":  {"message":"The requested resource could not be found, or a request was received   using an HTTP method that is not supported by the mapped resource. (Original  error: That device doesn't know how to respond to 'mobile: 'scroll--it's   probably not using Appium's API)","origValue":"That device doesn't know how to   respond to 'mobile: 'scroll--it's probably not using Appium's   API"},"sessionId":"0b79ffed-89dc-66ca-27b0-cf6ef260181a"}
 > info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session/0b79ffed-89dc-66ca-27b0-cf6ef260181a/execute 500 3.576 ms - 449 
> info: --> DELETE /wd/hub/session/0b79ffed-89dc-66ca-27b0-cf6ef260181a {}
 > info: Shutting down appium session
 > info: [debug] Stopping selendroid server
 > info: [debug] Making http request with opts:  {"url":"http://localhost:8080/wd/hub/session/0b79ffed-89dc-66ca-27b0-cf6ef260181a","method":"DELETE"}
 > info: [debug] executing cmd:     C:\Users\GangaiahL\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 00bd9781 shell "am force-stop au.com.carsguide"
  > info: [debug] [SELENDROID] getSystemUiVisibility() after setting  = 0
  > info: [debug] [SELENDROID] getSystemUiVisibility() after setting  = 0
  > info: [debug] Stopping logcat capture
  > info: [debug] Logcat terminated with code null, signal SIGTERM
  > info: [debug] Cleaning up appium session
  > info: [debug] Responding to client with success:  {"status":0,"value":null,"sessionId":"0b79ffed-89dc-66ca-27b0-cf6ef260181a"}
  > info: <-- DELETE /wd/hub/session/0b79ffed-89dc-66ca-27b0-cf6ef260181a  200 1526.913 ms - 76 {"status":0,"value":null,"sessionId":"0b79ffed-89dc-66ca- 27b0-cf6ef260181a"}
```

Below is My code:
And the error thrown line-js.executeScript("mobile: scroll", scrollObject);

```
@Test
public void test() throws InterruptedException 
{

    System.out.println("TEST STARTED");

    driver.findElement(By.linkText("All Makes")).click();
    Thread.sleep(10000);
    //driver.findElement(By.linkText("AUDI")).click();
    WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.linkText("AUDI"));
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    HashMap<String, String> scrollObject = new HashMap<String, String>();
    scrollObject.put("direction", "down");
    scrollObject.put("element", ((RemoteWebElement) element).getId());
    js.executeScript("mobile: scroll", scrollObject);
```

Comment: are you scrolling down to the specific text ?

Comment: @Manidroid Yes i am scrolling down to a specific text element , which is a radio button and i have to scroll there and click on it to select

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.Do you have any scrollable view in your screen ?
2.If you have scrollable view in screen, do scroll on view not on text.

OR

Try this and ask:

```
String name ="AUDI";

driver.findElementByAndroidUIAutomator("new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().scrollable(true).instance(0)).scrollIntoView(new UiSelector().textContains(\""+name+"\").instance(0))");
```

OR

```
MobileElement element = (MobileElement) driver.findElementByClassName("android.widget.ListView"); 
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver; 
HashMap<String, String> scrollObject = new HashMap<String, String>(); 
scrollObject.put("direction", "down"); 
scrollObject.put("element", ((RemoteWebElement) element).getId());
scrollObject.put("text", "AUDI"); 
js.executeScript("mobile: scrollTo", scrollObject);
```

try this one.

I have solved the your problem and I have made the video which will helpful for everyone.

Please the solution for your problem in this link : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EdgStq4d0bQ.

Updated Answer :

I have updated my appium to 1.5.3 and fixed your issue & it will help for future also.
 Please refer this video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bT3tqaLNn-Y

Comment: Yes scrollable view is in the screen, i did try with that . still does not work. This was the first try i gave with scrolling ,since it was not working, i did try using js.executor

Comment: did you try above one ?

Comment: can you post the uiatomator screenshot with UI hierarchy viewer ?

Comment: added the screen Model,please have a look at it.

Comment: I have add one way to scroll try that & let me know, regarding direction you mention according

Comment: @Manidroid......thanks for that code...throwing the below error org.openqa.selenium.UnsupportedCommandException: The requested resource could not be found, or a request was received using an HTTP method that is not supported by the mapped resource. (Original error: That device doesn't know how to respond to 'mobile: 'scrollTo--it's probably not using Appium's API) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)

Comment: @lokesh is your problem solved or still stay with issue ?

Comment: thanks for followup....i was sick yday sorry didt come back to you. This issue still exists, i can share you the APK if you are happy to help me out on this?

Comment: sure, please share apk with this mail id along with your scenario : tech.tock.tech@gmail.com

Comment: I have sent u an email with Apk, please let me know if you have received the email and able to dowland the file..

Comment: sure, let me try it

Comment: @Lokesh please check above youtube link and let me know

Comment: Thanks a heap it works fine as per the video, but still have few concerns have sent u an email with the list. Such as for the latest version of appium 1.4.16 it still does not work, the ver it is working is 1.4.13. I guess for the latest ver 1.4.16 appium has depricted scroll ? If yes what will be the other workaround / solution for using it in the latest and future appium release version if they continue to depricate this. Also found the by.linktext needs to be used instead of by.name.

Comment: Is this working with Appium v1.7.2? I have tried the same code and ended up with the following error - org.jbehave.core.embedder.PerformableTree$SomethingHappened@3574f811: org.openqa.selenium.UnsupportedCommandException: Unknown mobile command "scroll". Only shell commands are supported. (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)

Comment: Doesn't work with Appium 1.7.2 and Java client 5.0.2.

Answer (score 0):

I believe a lot of scrolling functions have been removed. This includes the common `scrollTo()` method. If you want to be able to scroll you need to use the `driver.swipe(int startx, endx, starty, endy, duration)` command.

You can build some good scrolling methods off of this method if you use it with; element location, size and screen size. (Note for some reason the returns are different in comparison between Android and iOS)

Comment: i did try with driver.swipe,but still no luck. see the below code for that -    driver.findElement(By.linkText("All Makes")).click();
   Thread.sleep(10000);
   driver.swipe(720, 1600, 720, 698, 1000);

Comment: If you are doing this on an iOS device it could potentially cause the magnifying glass appear. To fix that just lower the duration to `100`

Comment: i am trying out on Android and its not working....yet to try on iOS will give a try.

Comment: In that case I would check that the points you are selecting are within the scrollable items area. You can see the devices screen size via `driver.manage().window().getSize().getHeight()` and `.getWidth()`.

Remember this is how an Android devices pixels are oriented [link](https://www.google.ca/search?q=Android+pixel+position&espv=2&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiE9_f68sjPAhVq5oMKHZB0CJ0Q_AUICigD&biw=1600&bih=770#imgdii=9pDF2ngDlmjcIM%3A%3B9pDF2ngDlmjcIM%3A%3BZFZK80NrSYslRM%3A&imgrc=9pDF2ngDlmjcIM%3A)

Comment: will try that out and let u know

Answer (score 0):

Use below code, It should work :

**For swipe UP:**

```
driver.swipe(350,800,350,350,2000);
```

**For swipe DOWN:**

```
driver.swipe(350,350,350,800,2000);
```